# Network diagram based on Cisco ACL and other firewall rules

Tags: network, firewalls, cisco

Are there any tools for automated building network diagram from ACL rules or any other firewall rules?

Comment: Yes, there are.  Redseal is one of them.  Product recommendations are out of scope for this Stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Cisco it might be easier to build a network topology diagram using Cisco Discovery Protocol than firewall rules or ACLs even if manually done.